# WordPress - Choose From A List Of Posts To Display On A Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fairly experienced in the ways of WordPress but have come across something that has me stumped.

I have a number of pages which are 'Treatments' and a custom post type called 'Staff'.

Everytime I create a treatment I want to be able to choose 1 or more staff members who are qualified to carry out that treatment.

So my question is, how do I set up WordPress to allow me to select from a number of staff members?

What the staff post contains is essentially a profile and I want to be able to pull that into the treatment.

In my mind I am envisaging it as either a series of check boxes within each of the events that displays all staff members

OR

That might be overkill if staff numbers grow significantly and therefore maybe some kind of repeater field with a drop down that displays the staff names.

I know I could do this with a number of different templates for the treatments and some categories or tags attached to the staff members, but it is better to do this with one generic template.

All thoughts to help me towards a solution are greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Study the database structure of wordpress. Where all staff details are stored and treatments then find a co-relation between them. Next step is to develop a page for it, with some custom coding in wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  There is no relationship between the two so I'm not sure this really helps.  What I am trying to do is to create the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easy alternative solution would be to use [a plugin such as this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/). It's for managing participants, but it also works for things like keeping track of staff.

As for putting the staff information in posts, that plugin has a shortcode `[pdb_single]` that will list a single person's information. You can find out more information on shortcodes by reading the "other notes" page on the plugin page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm reluctant to use a plugin as I'm sure this is probably a very common task and a plugin is perhaps overkill.  I always like to use a non plugin solution where possible.

Comment: @Johnny I believe your only non-plugin solution here would be to manually add the staff members' information to the posts, but that'll take forever to update when their information changes. There's also the possibility that you'd miss a post. Also, not all plugins extend functionality, some just make tasks easier to do.

Comment: Yes I always code for an update once but show changes everywhere solution otherwise it defeats the purpose of using a CMS in the first place.  I'll carry on looking around for some code but you would think actually that is something that is quite common practice.

Answer (score 0):

Super easy.

Create a custom function holding all of your staff members information. When creating a new 'treatment' post, call the appropriate staff members information using the custom fields. If the staff member is provided in the custom field, and if the staff member is found it will output the staff members information. You'll have to modified your treatment page to output the custom fields output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have an example of this?  It's a little vague for me to pick up and run with at the moment.